# iPhone is there a way to allow a user to rate the app from within it?

Tags: ios

I have seen some apps with a button to rate the app.  It brigs them to a page that always them to rate that app.

I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anybody know how to do this? I fred googling it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015470/how-do-you-prompt-the-user-to-rate-your-iphone-app-without-waiting-for-them-to-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Appirater by Arash Payan. It's easy and clean ;)

http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

Comment: If there are two identical answers, it is advised that you choose the one that was written first as the accepted answer.

Comment: You're welcome, that's why we're here. @coneybeare I think we asked the question at same time b/c I didn't see your answer, even that my only intention was help. Sorry if I bothered you :(

Answer (score 2):

The most well known way to do this is an open source library called [AppIRater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater), but I have also seen [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) and people roll their own versions of the simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Appirater is good, but using the Game Center is better, because it allows to rate inside the app (without switching to iTunes). Check out Apple's GameCenter API.

Comment: Can you give some more detailed links to the methods or way of doing you are talking about ?

Comment: You can open any your iPhone game with Game Center and open Game Center then. You'll see 5 stars and you can rate an app there. I haven't figured it out in code yet, but this is the way I'm going to dig in next versions. Hope this is helpful.